ArcGIS Pro Crashing when using .project_as() on Spatially enabled dataframe
I'm trying to change the spatial reference of my shape column for a spatially enabled dataframe. My spatial reference currently has the wkid = 32165. I would like it to have wkid = 4326.
sedf['SHAPE'] = sedf['SHAPE'].apply(lambda x: x.project_as(4326))

When Running this ArcGIS Pro just crashes after 10 minutes. I've ran many other spatial functions on this dataframe and have not had crashed previously. The are almost 70000 rows in this dataframe, but I don't feel the quantity is the reason it is crashing. Let me know if there are any code changes I can make to fix this problem.

Edit: I've modified my code to use the project() function instead.
sedf['SHAPE'] = sedf['SHAPE'].apply(lamdba x: x.project(geometries = x, in_sr = 32165, out_sr = 4326))
It now returns an empty array which doesn't really fix my problem.

The arcgis.geometry.project() function works much better as specified in my comment above. Another thing to note about his function is that the input for geometries is a list not an individual geometry.
sedf['SHAPE'] = sedf['SHAPE'].apply(lamdba [x]: x.project(geometries = x, in_sr = 32165, out_sr = 4326)[0])

